# Opencart language switcher

Tags: opencart

I'm trying add a new language to opencart version 2.1.0.2. I've uploaded the language files and added the new language via localization->languages. Administration language works fine however the site language only changes when default language is set trough admin panel. language drop down menu does not change the site language. Anyone can help?

thanks in advance

Comment: Try opening your site trough incognito , and see if you can see the language switcher

Comment: i can see the language switcher through incognito. mean while i was trying to figure out how controller logic works and it appears language function in the controller/language.php  is unable to set cookie language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue:) It appears somehow i broke the form in the catalog/view/default[or your theme]/common/language.tpl file (i've added some css and javascript files manually).

For anyone encounter a similar issue, you need to be sure that **the form in the language.tpl file** 
(`<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="language">`)

**posts the hidden input field** (`<input type="hidden" name="code" value="" />`)

**with the value of** the language code that is taken from the **href atribure** of the a tag within the dropdown list
 `<a href="<?php echo $language['code']; ?>">`

I'm not writing the exact way i solved the issue because it is far too messy to suggest someone else to use it:) but basicly with some javascript (even better with jquery) you need to assign the value of href attribute of the a tag to the value attribute of the hidden input field

if your language switcher does nothing or give you a page not found error  or an internal server error you might have a similar issue